# Heroku Scheduler doesnt change DB automatically - Script works if executed manually

Tags: python, heroku

I am using the free Heroku Scheduler add-on for two tasks.
(Small tasks which take less then 10 minutes should be easily handeled by Heroku Scheduler).

In the logs I see the Heroku Scheduler executing but it seems not to do anything.

Here is the task (my_task.py):

```
from alchemy import db_session
from models import User

all_users = User.query.all()
for user in all_users:
    if user.remind_email_sent == False:
        print "SEND REMIND EMAIL HERE", user.id
        setattr(user, "remind_email_sent", True)

db_session.commit()
```

Here is the task in heroku scheduler:
[image]

The logs: heroku scheduler is executed (but I see no prints):

```
Aug 10 14:31:26 monteurzimmer-test app[api] notice Starting process with command `heroku run python my_task.py` by user scheduler@addons.heroku.com
Aug 10 14:31:32 monteurzimmer-test heroku[scheduler] notice Starting process with command `heroku run python my_task.py`
Aug 10 14:31:33 monteurzimmer-test heroku[scheduler] notice State changed from starting to up
Aug 10 14:31:34 monteurzimmer-test heroku[scheduler] notice State changed from up to complete
Aug 10 14:31:34 monteurzimmer-test heroku[scheduler] notice Process exited with status 127
```

**EDIT:**

Okay there is indeed an error, in the logs I was not displaying `info`. The error shows up here:

```
Aug 10 15:02:32 monteurzimmer-test app[scheduler] info bash: heroku: command not found
```

---

If I run the script manually (`heroku run python my_task.py`) through the heroku CLI it works fine, all items of currently 6 users are set to `True`

So why the scheduler does not work here? There is indeed an error, see the EDIT.

Right now it is a small test database, in future it is planed instead of the print to send an email to each user, there will be a few hundred users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I found the error, the solution is actually very easy. It tells me:

```
bash: heroku: command not found
```

Which means heroku is already executing bash, and therefore does not know the command heroku. You are already in your project folder, simply remove `heroku run` and thats it:

```
python my_task.py
```

As a note here: It took me very long to find the error. I assumed there is no error, because I never display the `info` stuff in the logs (I use LogDNA). So you should be looking on everything in the logs in such cases.